# Autogenerate timestamp postgres loopback 4

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, loopback, loopback4

how can I autogenerate a timestamp in Postgres via Loopback 4?
I tried this but it didn't work:

`@property({ type: 'Date', generated: true, autoGenerated: true, postgresql: { dataType: 'timestamp with time zone', extension: 'now()' }, }) timestamp?: Date;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways to achieve this.

Solution 1:
Specify it directly in your database, for example

```
created_on timestamptz DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Solution 2:
Add it in your model

```
@property({
  type: 'date',
  default: () => new Date()
})
created? : Date;
```